# UI not updating after deleting one element from array list

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I am writing a chat application. On click of a button I am trying to remove selected friend from list And its working properly but on removing the friend the UI is not getting updated

```
  private void removeFriend(String remfri) {
       removefri = remfri;

            {
                try {
                    Constants.connection.getRoster().setSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.accept_all);
                    Constants.connection.getRoster().createEntry(removefri, removefri, null);

                    Collection<RosterEntry> entries = Constants.connection.getRoster().getEntries();
                    for (RosterEntry entry : entries) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("name..."+entry.getUser()+"...type.."+entry.getType());
                        if(entry.getType()==ItemType.none)
                        {
                            Presence unsubscribe = new Presence(Presence.Type.unsubscribe);
                            unsubscribe.setTo(removefri);
                            Constants.connection.sendPacket(unsubscribe);

                           // usersList.clear();
                            usersList.remove(removefri);
                            Log.d("removed"," the best friend " + removefri);
```

Pasting code for refrence :http://pastie.org/8744959

Comment: call `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after deleting item...

Comment: i tried , but list is still not updating

Comment: try to print your array list using Logcat after you delete the item to double check if the item is being deleted.

Comment: @SMR : item is deleted i confirmed by login to gtalk .i cn see items are deleted .but on app ui its same

Answer (score 1):

Use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after removal

Comment: used same method also , but its not updating list

Comment: remove friend() fnctn is working as it removes friend from the list , but notify dataset is not working